# Error when using cx_Oracle SessionPool with multiprocessing

Tags: python, oracle, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, cx-oracle

I have a code to connect to an Oracle database (11g) that I need to make concurrent insertions. At the same time, I also need to retrieve the ID of the most recently added row. To achieve that, I did the following:

```
import cx_Oracle
import numpy as np
from typing import *
from multiprocessing import Process
from threading import Thread
import os
from itertools import zip_longest

Id = str
ip = "localhost"
user = "user"
userpwd = "pwd"
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, "1521", service_name='xe')
oracle_pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(user, userpwd, dsn_tns, min=5, max=5, increment=1, threaded=True, encoding="UTF-8")

class OracleConn:
    def __init__(self, pool=oracle_pool):
        self.pool = pool
        self.conn = self.pool.acquire()
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def add_vector(self, vector: np.ndarray, subgroup: Id, iddl: Id, annoy_status: int):
        vector_bin_string = vector.tostring()
        self.cur.execute(
            """ insert into VECTORS (vector, subgroup, iddl, annoy_status) values (:1, :2, :3, :4) """,
                (vector_bin_string, subgroup, iddl, annoy_status)
        )

    def get_lastrowid(self) -> int:
        self.cur.execute("""SELECT ANN_SEQ.currval FROM DUAL""")
        return self.cur.fetchone()[0]

    def close(self) -> None:
        self.conn.commit()
        self.pool.release(self.conn)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback):
        self.conn.commit()
        self.pool.release(self.conn)

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

def add_vectors(ids, vecs):
    with OracleConn() as conn:
        for i, idx in enumerate(ids):
            print(f"{os.getpid()}: ", conn.add_vector(vecs[i], idx, idx, 0))
            print(f"{os.getpid()}: ", conn.get_lastrowid())

    print(f"=============Finished Process {os.getpid()}")

n = 200
p = 4
start = 7000031 # Just some random ID to work with
numbers = list(range(start, start + p*n))
vecs = np.random.randn(n, 32)
values: List[List[int]] = list(grouper(numbers, n)) # This is a list of equal size lists of indices
p1 = Process(target=add_vectors, args=(values[0], vecs))
p2 = Process(target=add_vectors, args=(values[1], vecs))
p3 = Process(target=add_vectors, args=(values[2], vecs))
p4 = Process(target=add_vectors, args=(values[3], vecs))
processes = [p1, p2, p3, p4]
for pr in processes:
    pr.start()

for pr in processes:
    pr.join()
```

However, this code can only insert a few rows and then freezes (keep running) with some exceptions:

`File "<ipython-input-52-9d4c539598e9>", line 323, in get_lastrowid
    return self.cur.fetchone()[0]
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence`

And in another run:

`File "<ipython-input-4-94343739bd60>", line 30, in get_lastrowid
    self.cur.execute("""SELECT ANN_SEQ.currval FROM DUAL""")
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`

On the other hand, if I change the Process for the `from threading import Thread` class, it works perfectly. However, since my application is CPU-bound, I need to use multiprocessing to better process stuff. **Is there a way to make it work with multiprocessing**?

Note 1: I needed to use a sequence because Oracle 11g does not support Identity or something similar.

Note 2: SQL code to generate the database:

```
CREATE TABLE VECTORS (
    id NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    vector BLOB NOT NULL,
    subgroup INTEGER NOT NULL,
    iddl INTEGER NOT NULL,
    annoy_status SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE(subgroup, iddl)
);
CREATE INDEX VECTORS_ANNOY_STATUS_IDX ON VECTORS (ANNOY_STATUS);
CREATE SEQUENCE ANN_SEQ START WITH 1;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ANN_ID_TRIGG 
BEFORE INSERT ON VECTORS 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :new.id := ANN_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
END;
```

Note 3: Python 3.7.7

Note 4: cx_Oracle 7.3.0

Comment: Have you tried making a batch insert into oracledb using insert all statement? I think that would solve the issue.

Comment: @AlbinPaul thanks for your reply. However, I can not batch insert. The application requires it to be one single row at a time - we receive something like a stream of data through time. This code with many insertions and processes was just to test whether it was correctly inserting when simulating a production environment, where this could happen.

Comment: Try making your connections autocommit  insert queries then.

Comment: Even with autocommit it does not work.

Comment: Can you please post the full code? which version of python and cx_Oracle?

Comment: I have updated the description @gsalem. But it is Python 3.7.7 and cx_Oracle 7.3.0

Comment: Some thoughts: use `executemany()`, which is much more efficient than single row INSERTs with `execute()`.  See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html. Also try a RETURNING INTO clause in the INSERT instead of a second query (since the second query is yet-another-round-trip to the DB).

Comment: Can you edit the question to have a usable sample code? Your code fragment leaves a lot out, and I/we cannot get to try it out.

Comment: @gsalem The code can be executed now. This is a minimum working example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got to reproduce your case, and I better understand what is happening. Thing is the cx_Oracle-side connection pool cannot work with a multiprocess env. Each process in this case has it's own memory, ... and so the connection pool created by the parent process will not work as expected, and there's surely overlap. I think the best solution for you is to use Database Resident Connection Pool. [Here's a link to the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admin/managing-processes.html#GUID-82FF6896-F57E-41CF-89F7-755F3BC9C924), and and it's easy to use: add :pooled to the connect string that you have (if ezconnect, or add (server=pooled) to the tns entry).
When configured, you remove the pool creation from your python code, and instead of acquiring a connection from the pool, you open a connection to the server as usual. It is faster than normal connection, as there's no process to spawn then terminate.

Comment: In fact, I could fix the problem using `from multiprocessing import Semaphore`, and used it with value=1. It is feasible since the time I spent with each query is very short and does not have a great impact on my application.

Comment: You need to do that to make the pool work for you. Taking your code, I modified it to spawn 10 processes instead of 4, noting that you create a pool with 5 connections. All 10 processes could acquire a connection in the pool, but then get an error. This means that the pool does not work as expected, as it does with threads instead. Using semaphores will make it 'work', but I'm not sure you won't run into troubles later on. I did not really understand why threading does not suit your needs.